# Creating a 2010 SharePoint Workflow Condition "Is one of " or "Starts with"

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I want to create a 2010 SharePoint Designer workflow condition based on multiple options. For example, if a drop-down menu option has X, X1, X2, X3, Y, Z as a choice; I would like to create a condition that does, "If  is one of ["X2", "X3", "Y", "Z"] send email message. I do not see an option for the "is one of" condition. Is there a way to create the "is one of" condition?

I would also like to create a condition, "If  starts with "X" send email message. When I attempt to add the "starts with" condition, I do not have an option to write what I want it to start with. The only option I have is to pick the "X, X1, X2, X3, Y, Z" from the drop-down field. Is there a way to manually type what you want the condition to start with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copy the option value in a string variable and then perform your conditions like "starts with". SharePoint will then give you options of every string manipulation and logical operators.

Also I can suggest one more option, why not create a calculated field which is true or false depending on the option selected. You can create a formula which will be TRUE for few options and false for rest. Then in the workflow just check that calculated field's value to send the email.

Both will work in my opinion.

Comment: +1 for the Calculated Column suggestion. You can even use Calculated Columns to format your Email message text, which your workflow then reads

Answer (score 0):

Are you using InfoPath forms? If so I would put a rule on that field in the form that says "If equals "x" or "Y" or "Z" set field in form "Send email" to Yes. Then in your workflow do a lookup to the "Send Email" field.. The If statement becomes. If "Send email" equals "Yes" send email...